# Will you call this pattern an Abstract Factory Pattern or Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Problem Statement: Write a program to build a house, house can be of the following types: Apartment, Individual House, Bungalow.
Kitchen is customizable: ItalianKitchen, ModularKitchen, StandardKitchen;
No of Bedrooms is customizable: OneBedroom, TwoBedroom, ThreeBedroom;
Drawingroom is customizable: StandardDrawingRoom, BalconyFacingDrawingRoom

Here are the classes and interface I have put together. Here are some of the things I would like to know:

1. Will you call it an Abstract Factory Pattern or Factory Pattern?
2. Do you see any problems with the design here?
3. What improvements can be made in this design?

House:

```
interface IHouse
{
    void BuildHouse(IKitchen kitchen, IDrawingRoom drawingRoom, IBedroom bedRoom);
}

class Apartment : IHouse
{
    public void BuildHouse(IKitchen kitchen, IDrawingRoom drawingRoom, IBedroom bedRoom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Building Apartment");
        drawingRoom.BuildDrawingRoom();
        bedRoom.BuildBedroom();
        kitchen.BuildKitchen();
    }
}

class IndividualHouse : IHouse
{
    public void BuildHouse(IKitchen kitchen, IDrawingRoom drawingRoom, IBedroom bedRoom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Building IndividualHouse");
        drawingRoom.BuildDrawingRoom();
        bedRoom.BuildBedroom();
        kitchen.BuildKitchen();
    }
}

class Bungalow : IHouse
{
    public void BuildHouse(IKitchen kitchen, IDrawingRoom drawingRoom, IBedroom bedRoom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Building Bungalow");
        drawingRoom.BuildDrawingRoom();
        bedRoom.BuildBedroom();
        kitchen.BuildKitchen();
    }
}
```

Kitchen:

```
interface IKitchen
{
    void BuildKitchen();
}

class ItalianKitchen : IKitchen
{
    public void BuildKitchen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Italian Kitchen Built");
    }
}

class StandardKitchen : IKitchen
{
    public void BuildKitchen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Standard Kitchen Built");
    }
}

class ModularKitchen : IKitchen
{
    public void BuildKitchen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Modular Kitchen Built");
    }
}
```

Bedroom:

```
interface IBedroom
{
    void BuildBedroom();
}

class OneBedroom : IBedroom
{
    public void BuildBedroom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One Bedroom Built");
    }
}

class ThreeBedroom : IBedroom
{
    public void BuildBedroom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Three Bedroom Built");
    }
}

class TwoBedroom : IBedroom
{
    public void BuildBedroom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two Bedroom Built");
    }
}
```

Drawing Room:

```
interface IDrawingRoom
{
    void BuildDrawingRoom();
}

class StandardDrawingRoom : IDrawingRoom
{
    public void BuildDrawingRoom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Standard Drawing Room Built");
    }
}

class BalconyFacingDrawingRoom : IDrawingRoom
{
    public void BuildDrawingRoom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Balcony Facing Drawing Room Built");
    }
}
```

The input will be an object defining the customization:

```
interface IHouseDefinition
{
     HouseType HouseType { get; set; }
     BedroomType BedroomType { get; set; }
     DrawingRoomType DrawingRoomType { get; set; }
     KitchenType KitchenType { get; set; }
}

class HouseDefinition : IHouseDefinition
{
    public HouseType HouseType { get; set; }
    public BedroomType BedroomType { get; set; }
    public DrawingRoomType DrawingRoomType { get; set; }
    public KitchenType KitchenType { get; set; }
}

public enum HouseType : int
{
    Apartment,
    Bungalow,
    IndividualHouse,
    Villament
}

public enum BedroomType : int
{
    OneBedroom,
    TwoBedroom,
    ThreeBedroom
}

public enum DrawingRoomType : int
{
    BalconyFacingDrawingRoom,
    StandardDrawingRoom
}

public enum KitchenType : int
{
    ModularKitchen,
    StandardKitchen,
    ItalianKitchen
}
```

Here are the factory classes I have designed:

```
interface IHouseComponentFactory<T, R> where T : class where R : IConvertible
{
    T GetComponent(R type);
}

class KitchenFactory : IHouseComponentFactory<IKitchen, KitchenType>
{
    public IKitchen GetComponent(KitchenType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case KitchenType.ModularKitchen:
                return new ModularKitchen();
            case KitchenType.StandardKitchen:
                return new StandardKitchen();
            case KitchenType.ItalianKitchen:
                return new ItalianKitchen();
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unrecognized KitchenType");
        }
    }
}

class BedroomFactory : IHouseComponentFactory<IBedroom, BedroomType>
{
    public IBedroom GetComponent(BedroomType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case BedroomType.OneBedroom:
                return new OneBedroom();
            case BedroomType.TwoBedroom:
                return new TwoBedroom();
            case BedroomType.ThreeBedroom:
                return new ThreeBedroom();
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unrecognized BedroomType");
        }
    }
}

class DrawingRoomFactory : IHouseComponentFactory<IDrawingRoom, DrawingRoomType>
{
    public IDrawingRoom GetComponent(DrawingRoomType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DrawingRoomType.BalconyFacingDrawingRoom:
                return new BalconyFacingDrawingRoom();
            case DrawingRoomType.StandardDrawingRoom:
                return new StandardDrawingRoom();
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unrecognized DrawingRoomType");
        }
    }
}

interface IHouseFactory
{
    IHouse GetHouse(HouseType type);
}

class HouseFactory : IHouseFactory
{
    public IHouse GetHouse(HouseType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case HouseType.Apartment:
                return new Apartment();
            case HouseType.Bungalow:
                return new Bungalow();
            case HouseType.IndividualHouse:
                return new IndividualHouse();
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unrecognized HouseType");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the factory assembler and the HouseBuilder(a helper class):

```
class HouseFactoryAssembler
{
    private IHouseComponentFactory<IKitchen, KitchenType> m_KitchenFactory;
    private IHouseComponentFactory<IBedroom, BedroomType> m_BedroomFactory;
    private IHouseComponentFactory<IDrawingRoom, DrawingRoomType> m_DrawingRoomFactory;
    private IHouseFactory m_HouseFactory;

    public static HouseFactoryAssembler Instance = new HouseFactoryAssembler();

    private HouseFactoryAssembler()
    {
        m_KitchenFactory = new KitchenFactory();
        m_BedroomFactory = new BedroomFactory();
        m_DrawingRoomFactory = new DrawingRoomFactory();

        m_HouseFactory = new HouseFactory();
    }

    public IHouseFactory HouseFactory
    {
        get { return m_HouseFactory; }
    }

    public IHouseComponentFactory<IKitchen, KitchenType> KitchenFactory
    {
        get { return m_KitchenFactory; }
    }

    public IHouseComponentFactory<IBedroom, BedroomType> BedroomFactory
    {
        get { return m_BedroomFactory; }
    }

    public IHouseComponentFactory<IDrawingRoom, DrawingRoomType> DrawingRoomFactory
    {
        get { return m_DrawingRoomFactory; }
    }
}

class HouseBuilder
{
    public static void BuildHouse(IHouseDefinition houseDefinition)
    {
        IKitchen kitchen = HouseFactoryAssembler.Instance.KitchenFactory.GetComponent(houseDefinition.KitchenType);
        IBedroom bedroom = HouseFactoryAssembler.Instance.BedroomFactory.GetComponent(houseDefinition.BedroomType);
        IDrawingRoom drawingRoom = HouseFactoryAssembler.Instance.DrawingRoomFactory.GetComponent(houseDefinition.DrawingRoomType);

        IHouse house = HouseFactoryAssembler.Instance.HouseFactory.GetHouse(houseDefinition.HouseType);
        house.BuildHouse(kitchen, drawingRoom, bedroom);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any behaviour varying here, so I'd call this **over-engineered** `void BuildHouse(HouseDefinition house) { Console.WriteLine($"{house.HouseType} Built"); Console.WriteLine($"{house.KitchenType} Built"); Console.WriteLine($"{house.BedroomType} Built"); Console.WriteLine($"{house.DrawingRoomType} Built"); }` does the same thing

Comment: @Caleth It's a program that I wrote for my understanding, why would it need a varying behaviour?

Comment: What is it you were hoping to understand? Hopefully what you do now understand is that picking a complex solution (in this case lots and lots and lots of OO and some sort of factory pattern [and really, who cares really which one it is]) and blindly applying it to a very simple problem simply leads to ridiculous levels of over-engineering.

Comment: Every class here does exactly the same thing as every other class that implement it's interface. You may as well just have one class per thing. And most of your interfaces are identical up to renaming.

Answer (score 2):

> Will you call it an Abstract Factory Pattern or Factory Pattern?

You're baking concrete factories into the useage, so it's not an Abstract Factory

> Do you see any problems with the design here?

It's horribly over-engineered. Most of your classes and interfaces are repetitious

> What improvements can be made in this design?

Start again from scratch, and build the *simplest* thing that has the desired behaviour.

E.g.

```
void BuildHouse(HouseDefinition house) { 
    Console.WriteLine($"{house.HouseType} Built"); 
    Console.WriteLine($"{house.KitchenType} Built"); 
    Console.WriteLine($"{house.BedroomType} Built"); 
    Console.WriteLine($"{house.DrawingRoomType} Built"); 
}
```

can replace the *entire* `IHouse`, `IKitchen`..., `IHouseComponentFactory`... hierarchy, because all you are doing is writing text based on the enum values.